# How to allow Lambda function to call itself recursively

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-sam

I've got an app that runs on Lambda and is accessible through APIGateway.

In my SAM template, I've set it up so that APIGateway can invoke my function.

```
  ConfigLambdaPermission:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    DependsOn:
    - MyFunction
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !Ref MyFunction
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
```

But now I  need the app to call its own function recursively.  I thought that I could just append a new ConfigLambdaPermission to my existing one like this.

```
  ConfigLambdaPermission:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    DependsOn:
    - MyFunction
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !Ref MyFunction
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
  ConfigLambdaPermission:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    DependsOn:
    - MyFunction
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !Ref MyFunction
      Principal: lambda.amazonaws.com
```

However, when the function tries to call itself, it throws the following error:

```
2019-01-27 14:27:56 - Aws::Lambda::Errors::AccessDeniedException -
User: arn:aws:sts::666666666666:assumed-role/my-app-MyFunction-166U166U166U1/my-app-MyFunction-1DJIJCDO1DJIJ 
is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource:
arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:666666666666:function:my-app-MyFunction-1DJIJCDO1DJIJ:
```

I'm not sure if I added the privileges incorrectly or whether there some other step I need to do to inform AWS that the privileges have changed.

Any idea how to correctly allow this lambda function to call itself?

Comment: I think the principal in this case is going to be the IAM role that the Lambda runs under: arn:aws:iam::aws-account-id:role/role-name

Comment: Yep.  You are correct.  Once to had the role referenced as the principle, everything worked great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Principal` in this case is going to be the IAM role that the Lambda itself runs under, which is as follows (replace *aws-account-id* and *role-name* as appropriate):

```
Principal: arn:aws:iam::aws-account-id:role/role-name
```

Comment: this worked for me too!. exact steps -> open the lambda - configurations -> permissions -> resouece based policy -> add permissions -> select account -> principal as "arn:aws:iam::1234:role/role123456" , some suitable name ...